# Showing the binomial identity of $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n}{n+k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to show the binomial $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n}{n+k}$$

I have tried the following
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n}{n+k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n}{n-k}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n}{n-k}$$

How do I obtain the summation index of $2n$ from the above two summations?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any identity. It's just simply writing

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}$$

and then noticing that in the second sum the terms can be written as $\binom{2n}{n+j}$ where $j$ runs from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I see the bigger picture - so we're partitioning the set of values that run from k = 0 to 2n, is it also fair to say the following is true? $\sum_{k=0}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{3n}{k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{3n}{k}+\sum_{2n+1}^{3n}\binom{3n}{k}$ or how would I go about increasing the coefficient of n, so for general $\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha n}\binom{\alpha n}{k}$

Comment: @joe_bill.dollar Yes, what you say is true. Depending on the specific sum in hand, it may be easier to split it in different ways (e.g. even and odd indices).

Comment: Please can you share an example of even/odd indices for my clarity

Comment: @joe_bill.dollar A trivial example is $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k$.